# Is it advisable to use a return statement inside an included recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have several cookbooks which include several other cookbooks, depending on each cookbook's needs.
The included cookbooks declare services which notify other services.

One of the included cookbook `common_actions` is included in all the other cookbooks as it contains actions common to all.

```
include_recipe 'cookbook1'
include_recipe 'common_actions'
include_recipe 'cookbook2'
# Several cookbooks have such includes, but 'common_actions'
# is included in almost all the cookbooks.

# cookbook specific conditional logic that should be
# executed only if some condition in 'common_actions' is true
```

Is it a wise idea to include a conditional return statement in the `common_actions` cookbook so that it will force the including cookbooks not to be compiled/executed based on that condition? For the purpose of this question, please consider any fake condition like:

```
if node['IP'] == 'xyz'
    # All including cookbooks should execute only IP is xyz
    return
end
```

Can a cookbook with such a return statement cause only certain cookbooks to run? Is it advisable?

Note: I am doing this because I do not want to copy-paste the same code in all the other cookbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you properly, this won't do what you're after because:

1. A recipe will only be included once, if there's multiples cookbooks in the runlist calling `include_recipe A::B` then recipe B of cookbook A will only be compiled once, successive calls will be no-op (won't duplicate the recipe resources).
2. The `return` statement will end the actual recipe compilation, in your case it will stop the compilation of recipe `default` in the cookbook `common_actions`.

What you can do is using `node.run_state`, it's a hash available only during the run.
You can use it to store another hash of conditions from your `command_actions` cookbookn for example.

```
node.run_state['IP_allowed'] = node['IP'] == 'xyz'
# Probabaly a little silly, but that's the easier I can think of
if node.chef_environment == 'Test' 
  if node['DoDebugLog'] == true
    node.run_state['LoggerLevel'] = 'debug' 
  else
    node.run_state['LoggerLevel'] = 'info'
else
  node.run_state['LoggerLevel'] = 'warn'
end
```

Now you can use those values in others recipes to control their behavior while still keeping the conditional definition in a central place.

In a recipe which should **not** run if `node['IP']` is `'xyz'` you'll start the recipe with:

```
return if node.run_state['IP_allowed']
```

And on one which should run **only** if `node['IP']` is `'xyz'` you'll start the recipe with:

```
return unless node.run_state['IP_allowed']
```

The other value could be used for logging from recipes in different environments  like this:

```
log "Message to log" do
  level node.run_state['LoggerLevel']
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You could put a top level return in like that or you can use a conditional on the include_recipe itself.